# Has this method ever been called inside a running JVM

Tags: java, jvm, coredump

Is there a way to figure out if a method ever been called inside running JVM. Let's say I have the following method information and I want to know if it has ever been called:

```
    "methodId": {
      "className": "InvokerParser",
      "filePath": "org/foo/commons/functors/InvokerParserformer.java",
      "methodName": "parser"
    }
```

Comment: You could use Aspect/J. Or just increment a static counter inside the method.

Comment: There is no running trace of program execution unless you're using a ***profiler***.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt aspect-oriented programming (AOP) is one option, do you have an example reference of how that can be done?

Comment: Is the method in code you control?

Comment: yes, I can control the method

Comment: The easiest way is to print a log message inside the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the application is running on HotSpot JVM, it is possible to get the information about the given method using HotSpot Serviceability Agent.

Here is a tool that checks whether the method has been called in a running JVM.

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.InstanceKlass;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Method;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class CheckMethodCall extends Tool {
    private static final String className = "java/util/HashMap";
    private static final String methodName = "get";
    private static final String methodSig = "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean[] result = new boolean[2];

        VM.getVM().getSystemDictionary().classesDo(klass -> {
            if (klass.getName().asString().equals(className)) {
                Method method = ((InstanceKlass) klass).findMethod(methodName, methodSig);
                if (method != null) {
                    result[0] = true;
                    result[1] = method.getMethodCounters() != null &&
                        method.getInvocationCount() + method.interpreterInvocationCount() > 0;
                }
            }
        });

        if (!result[0]) {
            System.out.println("Method not found");
        } else if (result[1]) {
            System.out.println("Method has been called");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Method has NOT been called");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CheckMethodCall().execute(args);
    }
}
```

It requires `sa-jdi.jar` in classpath (comes with JDK 8).

Run

```
java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar:. CheckMethodCall <pid>
```

where `<pid>` is Java process ID to check.

**UPDATE**

A similar tool for JDK 11+
Use `--add-modules=jdk.hotspot.agent` and export all the required packages.

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.InstanceKlass;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Klass;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Method;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class CheckMethodCall extends Tool {
    private static final String className = "java/util/HashMap";
    private static final String methodName = "get";
    private static final String methodSig = "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Klass klass = VM.getVM().getClassLoaderDataGraph().find(className);
        if (klass == null) {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
            return;
        }

        Method method = ((InstanceKlass) klass).findMethod(methodName, methodSig);
        if (method == null) {
            System.out.println("Method not found");
            return;
        }

        boolean called = method.getMethodCounters() != null &&
                method.getInvocationCount() + method.interpreterInvocationCount() > 0;
        System.out.println("Method " + (called ? "has been" : "has NOT been") + " called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CheckMethodCall().execute(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks @apangin . will this catch classes loaded through reflection ?

Comment: @JauL Yes - any class currently loaded in the VM. But note that the class name, the method name and the method signature should be specified in the class file format described in JVMS.

Comment: It seems that the `sa-jdi.jar` is only available in pre-JDK 9 releases and has been encapsulated since then. Is there any way one can use this API? I've only found the `jhsdb` tool

Comment: @JurajMartinka I updated the answer with JDK 11 version of the tool.

Comment: @apangin Thanks!
Just in case it isn't obvious (if someone is as unfamiliar with the module system as I am) this is what worked for me to make the agent api available to all code on the classpath:
`javac --add-modules=jdk.hotspot.agent  --add-exports "jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.oops=ALL-UNNAMED" --add-exports "jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.tools=ALL-UNNAMED"  --add-exports 
"jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED" --add-exports "jdk.hotspot.agent/sun.jvm.hotspot.classfile=ALL-UNNAMED" CheckMethodCall.java`;
and the same when running the program via `java` command.